# Preserving number of rows in each file in a directory using Talend

Tags: talend

I have a folder with 10 text files in it. I need to count the number of rows in each file in that directory and append that count inside each file on a particular line number. This is to be done using Talend. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If your file is delimited (i.e. .csv) - you can use NB_LINE variable of tFileInputDelimited, it saves line-size of file AFTER component's done his job.
Then you may append this number to the END of your file using tFixedFlowInput -> tFileOutputDelimited
To make the same for every file in your folder, use tFileList with Iterate flow.

If you need to insert line number to your files for particular line number, not end of file, you could use limit in tFileInputDelimed. Rest of file you will append after inserting NB_LINE using specific 'header' value